# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2 in Arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I have a listener, when i click on the dates it will search for the arraylist and get the dates of what i click then when i change the month i will removed the dates then add the dates in my current month.

```
public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JsonArray datesIn = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SCHEDULE);
    for (int i = 0; i < datesIn.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = datesIn.getJSONObject(i);
        String dateD = c.getString(TAG_DATED);
        String statusD = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
        contact.put("Tag_dated", dateD);
        contact.put("Tag_status", statusD);
        contactList.add(contact);
        Date s = formatter.parse(dateD);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();;
        if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(0).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(0).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(0).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved"))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(1).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(1).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(1).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(2).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(2).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(2).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(3).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(3).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(3).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(4).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(4).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(4).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(5).get(TAG_DATED))){
            if(contactList.get(5).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(contactList.get(5).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

my problem is when i change the  month then click for the dates it has error.

```
public void onChangeMonth(int month, int year) {
    contactList.clear();
    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contact.put("Tag_dated", dateD);
    contact.put("Tag_status", statusD);
    contactList.add(contact);
}
```

Logcat error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is35y.png

Comment: `"Invalid index 2, size is 2"` means the size is `2`, so valid index is only `0`, and `1`

Comment: Your contactList size is 2 so you can access 0 and 1 index.

Comment: FYI: When an ArrayList has 2 elements (size of 2). The first element is at the index 0 and the second is at the index 1. And there is nothing at the index 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is strait forward, size is two. Index starts at 0, so indexes available are 0 and 1 not 1 and 2.
Your loop may need size - 1.

Instead of hardcoding your statements such as :
if(formatter.format(date).equals(contactList.get(0).get(TAG_DATED))){

Try doing it in a loop where you go

```
public void updateToast(Date date, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList) {
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (formattedDate.equals(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_DATED))) 
        {
           if(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied"))
           {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"S",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
           } else if(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Reserved")) 
           {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
           }
        }
    }
    // If here then its not found in any lists throw up your other text.
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Some of this may be a bit out as its done free hand in here.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `ArrayList` called `contactList`, and adding one element to it; then you're trying to retrieve several elements from it!

Answer (score 0):

In your code onSelectDate you are saying:

```
contactList.add(contact);
```

It will add Hashmap into your list just once, so you could use contactList.get(0) on your Arraylist. But going  forward you are saying

```
contactList.get(1);//even two
```

So it doesn't have element beyond first and hence it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

lets refactor your code little bit, lets get rid of this ugly nasty and unsafe if/else horror, and change it to nice and lovely loop

```
    boolean found = false;
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
        if (formattedDate.equals(contactList.get(i).get(TAG_DATED))) {
            if (contactList.get(i).get(TAG_STATUS).equals("Occupied")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "S",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (contactList.get(1).get(TAG_STATUS)
                    .equals("Reserved")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "R",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NP",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

this code should do exactly same thing as yours but it shouldnt give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception

Comment: Think you need to move your if (!found) check outside of the for loop, otherwise it's going to call it every time its not found on the loop iteration. (however I guess it depends if that's what he wants or not)

Comment: @VeenarM you are right, i didn't count brackets right, it was very sloppy, thx